# Smooth approximation of a five phase piecewise linear function

Tags: linear-programming, approximation

I am looking for a smooth (continuous differentiable) approximation of the following five-phased linear function:
$$
P(U, R, P_r) = \begin{cases}
R(U_{max} - U) + R(U_{up} - U_{max}) + P_r; & U \geq U_{max}\\
R(U_{up} - U) + P_r; & U_{up} < U < U_{max}\\
P_r; & U_{low} \leq U \leq U_{up}\\
R(U_{low} - U) + P_r; & U_{min} < U < U_{low}\\
R(U_{min} - U) + R(U_{low} - U_{min}) + P_r; & U \leq U_{min}\\
\end{cases},
$$
Here $U_{max} \ge U_{up} \ge U_{low} \ge U_{min} $ are the breakpoints and bounds of the variable $U$. $P_r$ and $R$ are a given setpoint value and slope of the line respectively. Also, $P$ has bounds as $P_{min} \leq P \leq P_{max}$.

I am trying to define these constraints as nested max functions and then apply the smooth approximation.
Such that: $$F(x) = \max\{0,x\}, \quad for \quad x \in \mathbb{R}$$

By picking any positive number $\epsilon > 0$:

$$F^\epsilon(x) = \epsilon \ln \left(1+ \exp(x/\epsilon)\right), \quad for \quad x \in \mathbb{R}$$

with bound verification:

$$F^\epsilon(x) - \epsilon \ln2 \leq F(x) \leq F^\epsilon(x)$$

Comment: If I further simplify the function as: 
$$
P(U, R, P_r) = \begin{cases}
R(U_{up} - U) + P_r; & U_{up}  < U \leq U_{max}\\
P_r; & U_{low} \leq U \leq U_{up}\\
R(U_{low} - U) + P_r; & U_{min} \leq U < U_{low}\\
\end{cases},
$$